# installing Ubuntu onto the same HD

Tags: dual-boot

I have XP Pro on C drive and there is plenty of room left on said drive. I read to use "Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop". It seems to create to partition but does it also install Ubuntu at the same time?  I can put Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit onto my USB drive. Is making the partition with  Windows installer a two part operation? First make the partition then go and do the install of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows installer does not create a partition. It instead installs Ubuntu as a program. This installer only works on Windows 7, so do not try it on XP.

To dual-boot the easy way:

1. Download the Desktop Installer (it should be an ISO file) and burn it to a CD.
2. Boot your computer into the CD (you may have to modify the boot order in your BIOS)
3. Choose **Install Ubuntu**.
4. When asked how you want to install Ubuntu, choose **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP**.

Follow the installation procedure and you should be fine. You do not need to create any partitions because Ubuntu does that for you. If your computer boots into Windows instead of GRUB, reboot into the CD, choose **Try Ubuntu Before Installing**, and open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then, run `sudo apt-get install boot-repair` followed by `gksudo boot-repair`. Reboot again and Ubuntu should work fine.